# Strange PHP Session behavior

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, session

I'm being puzzled by the strange behavior of some session variables. The "token" variable in particular.

This is how I create it in **index.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['token'] = sha1(rand(7451, 98632)); // Lets name it "something"
?>
```

Then I do a POST with AJAX and pass that variable to another script, the **ajax_io.php**:

Inside the **ajax_io.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST['token'] != $_SESSION['token']) die('Horribly');
?>
```

My check always "dies", while the token is passed correctly by the javascript AJAX post in index.php, the $_SESSION['token'] in the ajax_io.php is different than the one created in the index.php.

e.g. in ajax_io.php:

```
The $_POST['token'] appears as "something"
but,
$_SESSION['token'] appears as "something else"
```

It's like if the AJAX post is requesting the index.php (somehow) that creates another token and then requests the ajax_io.php to do the functionality requested.

Here is the Javascript AJAX request:

```
var token = '<?php echo $the_token; ?>';    
$.post("ajax_io.php", {
        token: token
    }, function(data) {
        // Do something with data
    });
```

**UPDATE**:

I haven't mentioned that on the real script, there is a foreach loop, and that loop is the cause of the trouble. It somehow rewrites the php token variable with a newly generated one on each loop but the script keeps the original value for setting the javascript variable.

```
$the_token = sha1(mt_rand(10, 100));
$_SESSION['tokens'][] = $the_token; // Notice the multidimensional array here

foreach(somethin) :
// do something other than setting any session variable
endforeach;
print_r( $_SESSION );
```

Output:

```
Array (
[tokens] => array (
[0] => b19477cb038d6e0f588b6631c1686c8e246b82d5 // The real one created at the beginning of the script
[1] => 51e57c94bfd5c81b11e8c48dc8002b1162f4cd84
[2] => 084c881c074678218a4394524f60d3867da84cb3
)
)
```

On this script if I echo out the $_SESSION I get an N amount of tokens, for example 3. But only the first one is the one created physically by my script, the other 2 where created by the loop. I've gone through the entire loop script but haven't found anything setting any sort of variables to the SESSSION.

Comment: Are you checking to make sure you don't overwrite the `$_SESSION` token on page load?

Comment: On the index.php file there is only one occurrence of the $_SESSION['token'] = "something".

Comment: OK there is something even stranger now. This appears to be browser related. On Firefox, if I shift-refresh the page (index.php) the new token doesn't match the token the ajax_io.php is getting from the session. On Chrome, either with normal refresh (F5) or shift-refresh or Ctrl+R. The 2 tokens never match. On Opera it works just fine.

Comment: What is `$the_token`? Why not just echo the actual session value?

Comment: The actual random token is being stored on a variable called $the_token that I pass onto the session like this: $_SESSION['token'] = $the_token; and then onto the javascript variable like this: var token = '<?php echo $the_token; ?>';

Comment: Using your code examples (only adding some code for display reasons), it works: http://jfcoder.com/test/settoken.php The thing that I would be wondering if whether the token was being overwritten on page load. Otherwise, I'm thinking there is something else going on that's not included in your question.

Comment: It is really weird. I made a quick test myself on a fresh file and it works.Now on the problematic script if I load the index.php file on the browser and on another tab I load the ajax_io.php and print the SESSION on both, both scripts have their own session token. The ajax_io.php doesn't declare anything and printing the session in index.php after creating the token and at the end of the script there is no change

Comment: @JaredFarrish let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2442/discussion-between-petsoukos-and-jared-farrish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the cause of the double request was an IMG tag on the rendered text inside the foreach loop. The tag had an empty src parameter, that was triggering a request in the background. That request was refreshing the generated key, but since it was in the background, the front-end part wasn't getting the new key. Stupid problem.

This question in now solved. (I hope)

Answer (score 0):

YOu just have bad logic. Dont every time check for token. When you do it, it overwrites it. Just generate it on need, not every time.

```
$_SESSION['token'] = (empty($_SESSION['token'])) ? gen_new_token() : $_SESSION['token'];
```

You can store time, for wich its valid and so on.

Comment: The logic works, I've pinpointed a problematic point in the script. It is in the While loop and is just a simple echo statement, when I comment that echo out of the script, the application is running as expected. It is probably a some kind of a bug... since that echo statement prints a LONGTEXT from the Database, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `.post` to `.ajax` as **synchronous**  and let us know what happens. Please post a barebones version of the script since what you posted works ok and the issue is probably a detail in the logic somewhere else.

Comment: There is an ECHO statement in the WHILE loop that is triggering somehow a new SHA1 string. .ajax does the same thing. I used .ajax the first time.

Comment: Well, an echo statement can't be triggering that (unless maybe if it happens before session_start()). So, the error happens That 's why you should post a thinned down version of your code, so someone can pin point where the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

I can't strip so much out from the script to post the code, the logic is the same as the original post, with the WHILE loop having about 50-60 lines more code.

I just found more tho. Browsers seem to be requesting the index.php file more than once.

**127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2011:19:38:40 +0300] "GET /cmdownloads/index.php?itsme=petsoukos HTTP/1.1" 200 11919**
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2011:19:38:40 +0300] "GET /cmdownloads/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2011:19:38:40 +0300] "GET /cmdownloads/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2011:19:38:40 +0300] "GET /cmdownloads/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2011:19:38:40 +0300] "GET /cmdownloads/js/script.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2011:19:38:40 +0300] "GET /cmdownloads/img/overlay.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
**127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2011:19:38:40 +0300] "GET /cmdownloads/index.php?itsme=petsoukos HTTP/1.1" 200 11980**
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2011:19:38:40 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209

One is being made by the user refreshing the page, but the other...? Can't find the source of that request.

Comment: This is so frustrating, I have converted the entire project into Codeigniter and same thing happens there. So far my conslusion is: it's browser related, since Opera works as expected.